# Using Tomcat manager in tomcat 7.0 + spring MVC, Webapp reload gives apachelifecycle exception

Tags: spring, exception, tomcat, spring-mvc, reload

Using Tomcat manager in tomcat 7.0 + sping MVC, Webapp reload gives apachelifecycle exception. It all starts up fine and works fine when started normally. After the startup for reloading the webapp, we use the tomcat manager. In tomcat manager, upon clicking the reload button it says reload successful ( this enables the start button). Upon clicking the start button in the tomcat it throws a apachelifecyle exception. Please help...

> 2013-03-27 01:13:39,153 [http-bio-443-exec-24] ERROR StandardContext -
>   Exception stopping Context with name [/webtest]
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webtest]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3913)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:364)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component
>   [WebappLoader[/webtest]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5521)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadedByThisOrChild(WebappClassLoader.java:2598)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks(WebappClassLoader.java:2515)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkThreadLocalsForLeaks(WebappClassLoader.java:2455)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1996)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1902)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:661)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
>     ... 26 more 2013-03-27 01:13:39,155 [http-bio-443-exec-24] INFO 
>   LifecycleBase - The stop() method was called on component
>   [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources@2d204c14] after stop() had
>   already been called. The second call will be ignored.

Comment: ... as they way, Java is optimized for the generation of `NullPointerException`,

Comment: We fixed this by changing the tomcat code for handling this see my comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this component?

```
The stop() method was called on component [org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources@2d204c14]
```

I would try to figue out. Maybe JMX or enable further logging or debug Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-O... Upon setting log to debug, Even though the tomcat says it has reloaded the webapp, it looks like it has failed to do that correctly...  2013-04-01 10:10:48,720 [http-bio-443-exec-6] ERROR StandardContext - Exception stopping Context with name [/webtest]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to stop component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/webtest]]

Comment: If so, start your Tomcat in debug mode, attach to the JVM with Eclipse (or else) and break into `org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:236)`.

Comment: :I am seeing a null pointer in the tomcat code base (7.0.30), Could this be the root cause?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadedByThisOrChild(WebappClassLoader.java:2598)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks(WebappClassLoader.java:2515)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.checkThreadLocalsForLeaks(WebappClassLoader.java:2455)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1996)

Comment: at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1902)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)

Comment: Might be the case. I you should write this to Tomcat's users mailing list.

Comment: Well I fixed the issue, the check for leaks feature of tomcat is hitting the null pointer issue for hte unloaded resources. Changed the WebappClassLoader.java in the tomcat's Catalina.jar to fix this. Now every thing is working fine. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: If you have found a bug, please report it! Let everyone benefit from.